# Website Scraping html class identification issues

Tags: android-studio, web-scraping, android-recyclerview, jsoup

I want to scrape MAL for character imgurl to later display using Picasso and name of character but am having troubles accessing the correct class files.
Here is the website under inspect. TYSM in advance.
[Inspect MAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMhfa.png)

Here is my CharacterList class which identifies the HTML classes

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ParseAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<ParseItem> parseItems = new ArrayList<>();
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_watch_list);

    configureBackButton();

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_character);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new ParseAdapter(parseItems, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Content content = new Content();
    content.execute();

}

private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CharacterList.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CharacterList.this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            //website url
            String url = "https://myanimelist.net/character.php";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
           
            Elements data = doc.select("tr.people");
            int size = data.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){ 
                String imgUrl = data.select("a.mr8.ml12.fl-l")
                        .select("img")
                        .eq(i)
                        .attr("src");

                String title = data.select("tr.mt24.di-ib.information")
                        .select("a.fw-b.fs14")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text();

                parseItems.add(new ParseItem(imgUrl, title));
                Log.d("items", "img: " +imgUrl + " .title: " + title);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I believe my ParseAdapter and ParseItem are working but just in case here they are

```
public class ParseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ParseAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ParseItem> parseItems;
private Context context;
public ParseAdapter(ArrayList<ParseItem> parseItems, Context context){
    this.parseItems = parseItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ParseAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.parse_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ParseAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ParseItem parseItem = parseItems.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(parseItem.getTitle());
    Picasso
            //with vs get()
            .with(this.context)
            .load(parseItem.getImgurl())
            .into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return parseItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_character);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_character);
    }
}
}



public class ParseItem {

private String imgurl;
private String title;

public ParseItem(){

}

public ParseItem(String imgurl, String title) {
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
    this.title = title;
}

public String getImgurl() {
    return imgurl;
}

public void setImgurl(String imgurl) {
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out nevermind. Here is the class identification part in case anyone is stuck later on.

```
Elements data = doc.select("td.people");
            int size = data.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
              
                String imgUrl = data.select("a.fl-l.ml12.mr8")
                       
                        .select("img")
                        .eq(i)
                    
                        .attr("data-src");

          
                String title = data.select("div.information.di-ib.mt24")
                
                        .select("a.fs14.fw-b")
                        .eq(i)
                        .text();
```